# What does it mean for a subset $A$ of the universe $M$ of an $L$-structure $N$ to be closed under $t^N$ for all $L$-terms $t = t(x_1, ..., x_n)$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

Initially I thought it meant closed in the sense of functions i.e if we apply an $L$-term $t$ to some elements of $A$, then the result stays in $A$. But, well, I am not so sure anymore since $L$-terms can be constants, so it doesn't make sense to 'apply' a constant.

Comment: Constants *are* functions - they're $0$-ary functions. Being closed under a $0$-ary function is the same thing as containing the element it corresponds to. (I'm not sure why this got downvoted, by the way, and I've upvoted to compensate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Initially I thought it meant closed in the sense of functions i.e if we apply an $\mathcal L$-term $t$ to some elements of $A$, then the result stays in $A$.

Quite correct...

The domain $M$ of a structure $\mathfrak A$ is a collection of "objects" (e.g. numbers) and we interpret the language in such a way that formulas are statements about the objects and their properties.

Terms are "names": the individual constant $0$ in the language of arithmetic is the name for the number *zero*.

To say that a subset $A$ of $M$is "closed under" (the interpretation of term) $t$, for every $t$, means that:

> according to the given interpretation, every term $t$ denotes an element of $A$, when its free variables are interpreted in $A$.

This is obvious for individual *constants*: either $t^{\mathfrak A} \in A$ or not.

But terms are built also from function symbols, like e.g. $+(x,y)$ in the language of arithmetic.

To say that $A$ is closed with respect to it means that every time we assign to variables $x,y$ values in $A$, the interpretation will assign to term $+(x,y)$ a value in $A$.

Some examples with $\mathfrak A = (\mathbb N, 0, s, +, \times)$.

Not all subsets $A$ of $\mathbb N$ are closed under $+^{\mathfrak M}$.

Consider e.g $A = \{ 1,2,3 \}$; we have that for $x=1$ and $y=3$, their sum is not in $A$.

The subset of $\mathbb N: \ A = \{ n \mid n \text { is Even } \}$, instead, is closed with respect to $+^{\mathfrak M}$.

Final example: no proper subset of $\mathbb N$ is closed under the *successor* function $s(x)$.